# Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error :unexpected character when I jekyll serve

Tags: jekyll, liquid

[the error happened when I enter jekyll serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr0XC.jpg)

[image: Console output from "jekyll serve" showing several Liquid Warning syntax errors for unexpected characters.]

For example:

> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 50): Unexpected character & in "site.duoshuo_share && site.duoshuo_username" in /MyBlog/_layouts/post.html

Comment: Please paste your code in addition to using a screenshot. Saves typing in answers.

Answer (score 3):

`Unexpected character &`:

You want to use `and` rather than `&&`.

```
site.duoshuo_share and site.duoshuo_username
```

---

`Unexpected character {`:

The error is actually the way you are referring to a variable. You can't use hyphens like that and you dont need to use `{{ }}` inside a `{% %}` tag.

Assuming it's in an `if` tag:

```
{% if tag[1].size > site.featured_condition_size %}
```

Or:

```
{% if tag[1].size > site['featured-condition-size'] %}
```